# donde esta el evento en crearDB.onupgradeneeded = e =>{}

Tags: javascript

Estoy en un curso de js y estamos viendo como usar la base de datos del navegador. En la linea: "crearDB.onupgradeneeded = e =>{}" cuando paso el "e" entiendo que estoy pasando un evento por parametro pero no entiendo cual es el evento. O acaso es que el metodo "onupgradeneeded" genera un evento?

function crearDB(){
const crearDB = window.indexedDB.open('crm',1);

```
    crearDB.onerror = ()=> {console.log('Hubo un error al crear la DB!!');}
    crearDB.onsuccess = ()=> {console.log('DB creada con exito!!'); DB = crearDB.result;}

    crearDB.onupgradeneeded = e =>{
        const db = e.target.result;
        const objectStore = db.createObjectStore('crm', {keyPath: 'crm', autoIncrement: true});

        objectStore.createIndex ('nombre', 'nombre', {unique: false});
        objectStore.createIndex('correo', 'correo',{unique: true});
        objectStore.createIndex('telefono','telefono', {unique: false});
        objectStore.createIndex('empresa','empresa',{unique: false});
        console.log('Columnas creadas correctamente');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento que estás pasando a la variable *e* es *onupgradeneeded*, el cual se activa cuando se intenta abrir una base de datos con un número de versión superior a su versión actual.